# js-selectize выбор из списка и ввод того чего нет, не сохраняет то что ввел

Tags: javascript

Поставил: **js-selectize**

Проблема в следующем, если в списке нет варианта для выбора, то мы вводим свой, вписали, потом если кликнуть мышкой в любом месте на сайте, введенный вариант он становиться пустым, я не разобрался как это решить, может кто-то сталкивался, подскажите.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-selectize').selectize();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://test.vl-it.ru/media/selectize/selectize.css">
<script src="https://test.vl-it.ru/media/selectize/microplugin.js"></script>
<script src="https://test.vl-it.ru/media/selectize/sifter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://test.vl-it.ru/media/selectize/selectize.min.js"></script>


<select name="modelshin" class="js-selectize" placeholder="Выберите или введите">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение, все банально просто, надо было смотреть настройки плагина )

create: true,
createOnBlur: true,

Comment: showAddOptionOnCreate: true, //кнопка добавить, если параметр create включен

Comment: а если кто хочет изменить название кнопки Add, открываем selectize.min.js ищем там Add и меняем на свой вариант, допустим Добавить. стили кнопки .selectize-dropdown .create

Answer (score 0):

Есть вот такое свойства, дает возможность написать, и добавить как бы, то есть можно выбрать, но если интер не нажать, то есть не добавить, то что ввел оно исчезает.

```
$("#select-beast").selectize({
  create: true,
  sortField: "text",
});
```

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/690767)

Comment: ок, понял......